# Checking whether the ringer and notification volumes are linked? (android)

Tags: android, notifications, linked-list, volume, ring

So I am trying to write an android app to control audio volumes -music, notifcations, media, etc. I wanted to detect whether or not the ringer and notification volumes were linked. The reason for this is so that the two seek bars could be moved together if they are linked. I am writing the app for android 4.1 as an FYI. I could not find any APIs that could help with that. Thanks everyone in advance.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can't do this. What you can do is get the volumes through the [`AudioManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html), but that will only get you the values, not whether they are linked

Comment: Really? wow, so would this be most efficient method to workaround that? : set notification volume to 0, set ringer volume to 1, then get both values, if they are the same, then they are linked.

Comment: I don't think that would do it. I'm guessing the linking of the volumes is an app specific thing for the Settings app. This means there's no real way of knowing for sure. You can easily test your hypothesis though by just writing that code and seeing for yourself

Comment: Yeah I ran that code I mentioned, it seems to work, but I would need test it on more devices, its annoying that google leaves out some of the more useful apis.